# docker not finding focal Release mariadb mac m1

Tags: docker, mariadb, apple-m1, mariadb-10.6

I'm attempting to run a make install script and I'm completely new to docker. Currently the docker portion of the script will not complete the mariadb container build.

```
FROM mariadb:10.6.14

# Install additional packages
RUN apt update && apt install --no-install-recommends -y \
    less \
    iputils-ping \
    net-tools \
    netcat \
    man \
    procps
```

The error that I get back is mentioning a missing focal Release file. 1) I'm not sure if that error is a red herring because I am so new to this environment, 2) I don't know how to get the script to point to the proper place for this error, if that is the solution.
Error:

```
5.716 E: The repository 'http://archive.mariadb.org/mariadb-10.6.14/repo/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
```

I went to that url and its an active url.

If I've missed any information that would help to solve this problem, please let me know.

I have tried using an older version of mariadb, and I just get similar errors, no Release file at a particular address.

Comment: I tried the following and got now errors - `podman run --rm -ti  mariadb:10.6.14 apt-get update -y`. There was a release happening about when you wrote this to the server may have been slightly overloaded with mirroring and new packages. 10.6.17 coming soon.